# Need to change the default Border color as RED in the excel

Tags: firefox

By default the border color is black but i need to change the default Border color as RED in the excel

**Note:**
Where ever i click the cell the border should be displayed as "Red"

Comment: Why is tagged firefox?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Cells.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone    
    ActiveCell.Borders.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)

End Sub
```

However, if you have any other borders in your worksheet, it will probably remove them!